# HowTo Sqlite-ContentObserver

Tags: android, sqlite, observer-pattern, contentobserver

I'm writing an android application, which main screen is based on a TabHost. Each Tab holds data selections from a sqlite database. Because in many different activities this data could be accessed and changed, I would like to develop a sqlite content observer to get track of the changes to single database tables. How would you implement such a SqliteObserver?